# Multiple Windows 8 Pro installs with one key

Tags: windows-8

I bought a Cyberpower PC without an OS to save money. When i got it, I installed Windows 8 Pro. Since then, I reinstalled windows 7 Pro. My question is; can I reinstall Windows 8 Pro using the same code key, or do I need to have a new key? Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install your Windows 8 copy onto the same computer if it works the same way as Windows 7 and earlier. It might get grumpy at automatic activation time, but a telephone call to their activation system usually solves any further problems.

If you want to put Windows 8 on another computer, it depends which kind of license you bought (OEM or retail). Retail licenses can be moved around all you want. OEM licenses technically are only for the system they were purchased for and can't be moved to a different machine, although in practice I've never had trouble as long as I removed it from the first machine beforehand.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply, it does certainly help. The license I purchased is a developers license.